# Can't install gnome extension "application menu"

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I can install all extensions without problems, but if I try to install an extension that would change the Activities button to an application menu it won't work.

Extensions I tried:

- application menu
- gno menu
- frippery application menu

I move the slider to on, the pop-up install appears, I click it but nothing happens. When I refresh the page, the slider is back to off.

Running ubuntu 16.04 with gnome 3.24

Comment: I have experienced the very same thing with 17.10 (currently moving towards beta).